# How to resize label in kivy to the size of my screen?

Tags: python, kivy

Hi I have created this kivy app. I just want to know how can i resize the label to the size of whole screen. And also if i resize the screen with mouse, the label also resizes itself to that screen. I know that to do this we need to use `size: root.width, root.height`. But that is done in the kivy file. What if i want to do this in my python file itself?
Thanks for your suggestions.

Pls refer to the code below:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyGrid(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.inner = GridLayout()
        self.inner.cols = 1
        self.add_widget(self.inner)
        self.inner.add_widget(Label(text = 'Hi!'))


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Window.height` and `Window.width` properties and `on_size` method to achieve this. As shown in the below modified code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MyGrid(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.inner = GridLayout()
        self.inner.cols = 1
        self.add_widget(self.inner)
        self.inner.add_widget(Label(text = 'Hi!'))

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.inner.height = Window.height
        self.inner.width = Window.width

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I tried using your formula, but it's showing me this error '[WARNING] <kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout object at 0x0000015D57C8EF28> have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.'

Comment: In my case there is no such warning while running the above code. Did you run the above code as it is? The warning indicates the GridLayout doesn't have cols/rows defined, but it has cols defined by ```self.inner.cols = 1```.

Comment: Hi! Thanks it's working. There was some mistake in my own code. Your solution is working really well.